# Expected Type qualifier before static ?

Tags: c, struct

Here is my code it shows error `Expected Type qualifier before static`
Looks Like it is not allowed in C but why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct st{
    int x;
    static int y;
    char z;
};
void main()
{

    printf("Sizeof(struct st) : %d\n",sizeof(struct st));

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `static` here?

Comment: What is the purpose you're trying to achieve by `static`?

Comment: It's not allowed because C isn't C++.

Comment: a common variable for variables of that structure

Comment: It would be valid in C++ but C is not C++.  They are very different languages.

Comment: Use `int main` instead of `void main`

Comment: @ErikW if int main is used will it solve the issue ??